# How to change the color of text just on one (front) side SCNText?

Tags: swift, scenekit, scene, scnnode, scntext

I am working with SCNScene where I place the SCNText node, so as a result, I get 3d text on the scene, the problem is that if I change the depth of the text it looks like a block of solid color, so it is hard to see what exactly on the screen, there are a few examples

[image]

[image]

I need somehow came up with the idea of how to make the text understandable even when it has a big depth value

I thought about drow the edges like this (I am not a good artist:)

[image]

Hope you got the idea

Or make the front side of the text lighter or in a different color, like this, so it will be more obvious for the user what it is written

Is there a way to do something like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntext):

> A text geometry may contain one, three, or five geometry elements:
>
> If its extrusion depth is greater than zero and its `chamferRadius`
> property is `0.0`, the text geometry has three elements, corresponding
> to its front, back, and extruded sides.
>
> SceneKit can render each element using a different material. For
> details, see the description of the `materials` property in `SCNGeometry`.

So you can set an array of materials, with one `SCNMaterial` instance for the front, and another material used twice for the back and sides.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to differently "colorize" the front and side parts of 3D text in SceneKit is to use two text nodes under a common parent container. Container allows you simultaneously move and rotate both text child nodes.

```
let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView
sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
sceneView.backgroundColor = .black

// Nodes
let container = SCNNode() 
let frontText = SCNNode()
let backText = SCNNode()

container.addChildNode(frontText)       
container.addChildNode(backText)
sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(container)

// Red stuff
backText.geometry = SCNText(string: "Hi", extrusionDepth: 10.0)
backText.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSColor.red

// White stuff
frontText.geometry = SCNText(string: "Hi", extrusionDepth: 0.005)
frontText.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSColor.white
frontText.position.z = (10.0 / 2) + 0.005
```

[image]